# How to call static class in a button Android

Tags: java, android

How can I call the `MyDialogFragment` in the button?

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // ***HERE***   
            }
        });
}
```

#### MyDialogFragment:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog

        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_in, null))

        // Add action buttons
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // sign in the user ...
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                MyDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
            }
        });      

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not _call a class_. You _call a method of an object_.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `how can i call the MyDialogFragment in the button? `

Comment: do you actually need to show a `Dialog` when a `Button` is clicked?

Comment: ALREADY FIXED! THANKS SIR!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want:
`new MyDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");`

Answer (score 1):

```
void onClick(View v){
  FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment();
  // or statically as
  // MyDialogFragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(getBaseContext(), MyDialogFragment.class.getName());

  fragment.show(ft, "MyDialogFragmentTag");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example from the Android SDK docs may help.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

```
public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
        MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .create();
    }
}
```

The activity creating this fragment may have the following methods to show the dialog and receive results from it:

```
void showDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyAlertDialogFragment.newInstance(
            R.string.alert_dialog_two_buttons_title);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}

public void doPositiveClick() {
    // Do stuff here.
    Log.i("FragmentAlertDialog", "Positive click!");
}

public void doNegativeClick() {
    // Do stuff here.
    Log.i("FragmentAlertDialog", "Negative click!");
}
```